# LibraryHelper: Library package:flutter_getx/content_page.dart is not loaded. This can happen for unreferenced libraries

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx, state-management

Please let me know how to solve this problem. and kindly guide why it occurs.

[image]

Comment: have you tried `flutter clean`?

Comment: Hi, You should not post code or anything else that is represented in textual form. Check [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for correcting me, Yes sure, I'll avoid images from the next time

Comment: Yes I tried Flutter clean, but the problem occurred again